# Django My heroku account isn't authorized to change my own app

Tags: django, heroku

An error comes up when trying to push changes onto heroku, it says I am not authorized to access my project, even though I created it. I was able to push changes to heroku before logging in, but after I logged in it doesnt allow changes from my bash console. When I log out it still won't accept changes.

Heres the error message

[image]

When trying the command in the Heroku documentation, I receive this error

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: App names are global on Heroku. Are you sure you own the `resume-project` app? That's the kind of name that might have been taken a long time ago. Try running [`heroku apps`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps) to see what apps you actually have.

Comment: @Chris Sorry if I made it unclear, resume-project is the remote I'm using, here's the error {$ heroku open --remote resume-project
 !    You do not have access to the app davidresumeproject.} and the website I'm trying to edit is my own, which is davidresumeproject.herokuapp.com

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. When you run `heroku apps`, do you see `davidresumeproject` listed?